# How to get value(s) of selected Item in listview - Android

Tags: java, listview, arraylist, selecteditem, selectedvalue

Am just new to Android (Java), I would like to get the value or values of the item user selected from my Custom ListView, below is a sample code i was trying to retrieve the data

```
ContactsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

       // String str= ContactsListView.getSelectedItem();
        //String selectedFromList = (ContactsListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        String val =  parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
        Log.i("Item", "Selected: " + val);       
    }
});
```

But this is what am getting

> 02-04 18:16:31.773 10255-10255/com.app.com.sms I/Item: Selected:
>   com.app.com.smsapp.ThreeStrings@42829718 02-04 18:16:33.323
>   10255-10255/com.app.com.sms I/Item: Selected:
>   com.app.com.smsapp.ThreeStrings@428297c0 02-04 18:16:34.463
>   10255-10255/com.app.com.sms I/Item: Selected:
>   com.app.com.smsapp.ThreeStrings@42829718

here is my adapter

> ```
> public class ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter extends
> ArrayAdapter<ThreeStrings> {
>
> private int layoutResource;
>
> public ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, List<ThreeStrings> threeStringsList) {
>     super(context, layoutResource, threeStringsList);
>     this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
> }
>
> @Override
> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>
>     View view = convertView;
>
>     if (view == null) {
>         LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
>         view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
>     }
>
>     ThreeStrings threeStrings = getItem(position);
>
>     if (threeStrings != null) {
>         TextView leftTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.leftTextView);
>         TextView rightTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rightTextView);
>         TextView centreTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.centreTextView);
>         TextView text_from = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_from);
>
>         if (leftTextView != null) {
>             leftTextView.setText(threeStrings.getLeft().toUpperCase());
>         }
>
>         if (rightTextView != null) {
>             rightTextView.setText(threeStrings.getRight());
>         }
>
>         if (centreTextView != null) {
>             centreTextView.setText(threeStrings.getCentre());
>         }
>
>         if (text_from != null) {
>             text_from.setText(threeStrings.getBottom());
>         }
>     }
>
>     return view;
> } }
> ```

```
public class ThreeStrings {
    private String left;
    private String right;
    private String centre;
    private String bottom;

    public ThreeStrings(String left, String right, String centre, String bottom) {
        this.left   = left;
        this.right  = right;
        this.centre = centre;
        this.bottom = bottom;
    }
    public String getLeft() {
        return left;
    }
    public String getCentre() {
        return centre;
    }
    public String getRight() {
        return right;
    }
    public String getBottom() {return bottom;}
}
```

in the listView am targeting **centre** as selected value. How do i get the value(s)/centre of the selected item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this below:-

```
ContactsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

      ThreeStrings threeStrings = (ThreeStrings)ContactsListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Log.i("Item", "Selected: " + threeStrings.getCentre());       
    }
});
```

Comment: @JoDee Is it working? If yes please Accept as Answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
String val = [yourList].get(position).getCentre();
```